# How to choose ant targets for execution dynamically.

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have 8 ant targets(for ex- a,b,c,d,e,f,g & h) in a ant script out of which only 5 targets should run every time. 4 targets(a,b,c & h) should run every time and one target between d,e,f & g should run along with a,b,c & h. Target h should run at bottom of remaining targets always. I am using eclipse kepler, trying to build Java EE project. Any help giving Ant script to fit this issue would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Come on guys, its been 4 hours and no reply from SO...

Answer (score 0):

```
<project name="dynTar" default="a">

<target name="a">

    ...  contents of Target 'a'  ...

    <antcall target="b"/>
    <antcall target="c"/>

    <input message="Choose a target: d, e, f, g" addproperty="dynT"/>
    <if>
       <or>
          <equals arg1="${dynT}" arg2="d"/>
          <equals arg1="${dynT}" arg2="e"/>
          <equals arg1="${dynT}" arg2="f"/>
          <equals arg1="${dynT}" arg2="g"/>
       </or>

       <then>
          <antcall target="${dynT}"/>
       </then>

       <else>
          <echo message="wrong value entered..."/>
       </else>
    </if>    

    <antcall target="h"/>    

</target>
```